# sqoop hangs when it import from sql server to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Am trying to import data from Sql server, Sqoop command is hanging after the below message. I have tested connectivity am able to do list database, tables and even select statement but it fails when it writes/ imports data in to hdfs. Could you please let me know your suggestion to solve this issue.

Hangs after this message:

```
 14/04/16 17:53:36 WARN mapred.YARNRunner: Usage of -Djava.library.path in mapreduce.admin.reduce.child.java.opts can cause programs to no longer function if hadoop native libraries are used. These values should be set as part of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the reduce JVM env using mapreduce.admin.user.env config settings.
 14/04/16 17:53:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1397650690524_0002 to ResourceManager at /192.168.155.61:8050
 14/04/16 17:53:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://<Master>:8088/proxy/application_1397650690524_0002/
 14/04/16 17:53:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1397650690524_0002
```

Thanks
Selvam

Comment: Check the nodemanager logs and post it.

Comment: Check write/user permission to HDFS .Also, check namenode should not be in safe mode.

Comment: ex: hadoop fs -chown -R user3350280:hadoopgroup /user/user3350280/sqoop/sqoopimportdirectorylocation/